# Gradle not syncing after update

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I was working on a project in android studio. Unfortunately, my harddisk started giving errors, so I backed up my project. Then, I bought a new harddisk and installed android studio(ver 3.0.1). I don't clearly remember the previous version of android studio that I used but I guess it was 2.6. Here comes my problem. When I started to sync the gradle,it gave me these errors.

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.4.0
Could not get resource 
'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/25.4.0/support-core-ui-25.4.0.aar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/25.4.0/support-core-ui-25.4.0.aar'.
Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/216.58.221.131] failed: 
Connection timed out: connect
Connection timed out: connect
```

Then I opened another one of my projects I got this error:

```
Error:Connection timed out: connect
```

I searched a lot and many are suggesting solutions related to setting a proxy and some are saying that the download repository is corrupted. I re-downloaded the repository but no luck. I used an external proxy software but still no luck.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You can try "Invalidate cache/Restart" from File menu and then check whether the issue is resolved.

Comment: I tried that too. What could be reason this is happening? No internet?

Comment: yes it create problem when not connected to internet so make sure for same

Comment: I'm connected to the internet and allowed android studio in the firewall too.

Comment: Oh sorry to bother you guys, I got the solution. It was because of my antivirus.